# how to monitor multiple locations in sftp using azure function or logic app?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

We need to monitor 10 different child folders for new files;

```
parent/child1
parent/child2
parent/child3
etc
```

If there are any new files in any of the `child` folders then move the files up to the `parent/`

**How do we solve this using a logic app or azure function?** I understand that there's an sFTP trigger for logic apps, but I do not believe it can monitor multiple locations.

Comment: I think you should give it a try first ....

Comment: How often do you need to check?

Comment: @Johns-305 hourly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think my thought could meet your requirements.

You could create a Recurrence with multiple triggers. Firstly create a logic app with a Recurrence and set the Interval time and Frequency then move your pointer over the arrow above the step where you want to add parallel branches. Choose the **plus** sign (**+**) that appears, and then choose Add a **parallel branch**. After that you could add actions you want.

And following is the result pic.
[image]

Maybe you could have a try, if you still have other questions, please let me know.

Comment: this is a beautiful solution thank you so much i will try it out and let you konw

Comment: @l--''''''---------''''''''''''， if my answer works, could you mark my answer, thanks!

Comment: There is a limitation here - you can only have a maximum of 10 triggers in a logic app